# Marking silicone nipples

Tags: bottle-feeding

Our daughter has severe reflux; so much that we give her cereal in her bottle at feedings to thicken it.  The thickened formula needs a slightly larger nipple opening.  Nothing new there I'm sure for many people here.

Her twin brother still uses plain formula, and hasn't graduated to the thicker formula, therefore still the thinner nipple hole.

They're currently differentiated visually by a small letter, which is hard to read from clear silicone.  We had an experiment with nail polish on one; that didn't survive a test wash in the dishwasher.

Is there anyway to mark silicone nipples in a non-leeching non-toxic way?

Comment: Can you clarify: are these twins, or differently aged children?  Probably not directly relevant but confused me reading the question.

Comment: would a Sharpie work? We have used [NameBubbles](http://www.namebubbles.com/Labels/Dishwasher-Safe-Name-Labels/Department.aspx?DeptID=65&) on dishwashed items, they last forever, but I think they might all be too big for nipples.

Comment: @joe yeah, twins, so two sets of bottles of the same rough size.

Comment: @RichHomolka do you know why she has reflux? It might be worth looking into http://chriskresser.com/rhr-how-to-treat-acid-reflux-in-babies-without-drugs

Comment: How about putting one set of nipples in a lingerie bag together?

Comment: @aparente001 segregation works fine until they're co-mingled and you need something per-nipple to distinguish them.  Thank you though.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to score a few notches in a non-critical part of the nipple (not entirely through - just lightly score the top) with a razor blade or similar.  Three in a row about 5mm apart or less should be fairly easy to identify by feel, especially if you do it twice on 180° opposite sides.  Do that for one size and not the other, and presto, easily identifiable nipples.

(We also had two sizes of nipples - not for this reason, but because the daycare complained that the nipples we preferred were too slow for the main feeding, so we provided a larger size for them to use if he was rejecting the slower one; thus S and M nipples mixed together.  I got used to identifying them by sight, but I considered a solution like this until I realized I didn't need to.)

Comment: In case it's not clear, 'non-critical part' means not near where the baby will notice it - along the base, where it will be covered by the retaining ring, is probably best.

Comment: this seemed a good answer (I upvoted), we kind of tried it, but specifically scoring definitely doesn't work.  Silicone seems to have almost a self healing ability.  any score marks blended in.  We cut them some, same issue. It got to the point where i took out a small notch.  Still easier to read the number.

I think this will sort out, for us, with time.  Eventually our boy will have the same size, and we won't worry about this.